# If statement to check if variable is equal to a string - Java

Tags: java, if-statement

This is a quiz app in Java. I am trying to compare the answer text stored as a variable (answeredOne) to the actual answer Prophase. I cannot get them to be equal. Do you see anything wrong with this code?

```
    EditText questionOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer_one);
    String answeredOne = questionOne.getText().toString();
    if (answeredOne == "Prophase") {
        score = score + 1;
    }
```

I keep getting zero when answering in the question.

Comment: `if ("Prophase".equals(answeredOne)) {...}`

Comment: Use .equals instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use == for strings. That would be checking the reference but not the value. Use .equals();

```
if (string.equals("otherstring")) {
    // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android uses java, so u can use .equals method.

```
   EditText questionOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer_one);
   if (questionOne.getText().toString().equals("Prophase")) {
      score = score + 1;
   }
```